# how to make vim syn regex to capture word with trailing space?

Tags: regex, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to make a vim regex to highlight word `house` in this example but only if followed by whitespace and only if sentence ends in semicolon.

```
herbert house mouse; bear care; house moose hat; // both instances of house highlighted
cow (house) banana goat; car bar; //house must NOT be highlighted
house beagle //house must NOT be highlighted
```

From my VIM syntax file:

```
syn match ngzRewLine '\w\+[^;]\{-};' contains=ngzRew
syn keyword ngzRew house contained
```

This works great except `(house)` is being highlighted.  What regex can I use that will only match words with trailing whitespace and a non greedy ending semicolon?

**EDIT**

To summarise, words in the `ngzRew` keyword group should be highlighted in the following cases:

- house mouse;
- cat house mouse;
- house banana;catfish house shoes;
- house;

No highlight should appear in the following:

- house
- cat (house) cheese;

`house` is used here as an example but there are other keywords in the `ngzRew` keyword group and the behavior should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way (this is probably not very convenient but I can't think of a better way because of the following whitespace)

```
highlight MyGroup ctermbg=green guibg=green
syntax match MyGroup /\(house\|car\)\ze\(;\|\s.\{-};\)/
```

Now it matches a `car` as well.

- [`\ze`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#/%5Cze) matches at any position, and sets the end of the match there,
- [`\s`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#/%5Cs) whitespace character,
- [`.`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#/.) matches any single character,
- [`\{-}`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%7B-) matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as few as possible,
- [`\(\)`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#/%5C%29)  braces can be used to make a pattern into an atom,
- [`\|`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#/bar) is "or" operator in a pattern.

Comment: Theres a bunch of different keywords in the `ngzRew`, not only house.  I just used house for the simplified example.  Im already highlighting the `ngzRew` group and it works including the trailing semicolon requirement except for the the `(house)' example.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I will think about it.

Comment: Now it should work. Sorry for not being able to find a better way, maybe someone else will. Hopefully, this will be good enough till then.

Comment: Problem is there are potentially hundreds of possible items in the ngzRew group.  But thanks for the effort!  At least I know what I thought was a trivial problem is actually harder than it looks.

Comment: I've got it!  A small modification to your suggestion.  I couldn't have done it without your help!  /\w\+\ze\(;\|\s.\{-};\)/ contains=ngzRew

Answer (score 1):

@ryuichiro gave me what I needed to find the answer so I've credited him for it.  But the full solution which allows for unlimited number of keywords is as follows:

```
syn match ngzRewLine /\w\+\ze\(;\|\s.\{-};\)/ contains=ngzRew contained
syn keyword ngzRew house contained
syn keyword ngzRew cheesecake contained
syn keyword ngzRew ...etc contained
```

Comment: It was in front of our eyes, I just couldn't see it in that moment! :-) Congrats!